# check for overlapping offset in php

Tags: php, preg-match, offset, strpos

How can i differentiate words in a string with overlapping offset. 
For example i have a string :

```
$s = "The famous team violin will showcase there violin talent to the fans who love violin.";
```

and then i have a keyword extraction which retrieves these words with offset :

```
team violin - 11
violin - 16
```

base on the result above the resulting word "violin" overlaps with "team violion"

the right result should be :

```
team violin - 11
violin - 43
```

this is the code for retrieving the offset of each keyword

```
foreach($keywordArr as $keyword)
{
preg_match('/\b'.$keyword.'\b/',$s,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
$keywordwithOffset = $keyword."\t".$match[0][1];
}
```

anyone got a piece of php script that could solve such thing?

Comment: Show the code you are using for the keyword extraction

Comment: Those offsets make no sense. "team violin" starts at word 7 in your phrase, and there's no word #16. Nor are your phrases at characters 11 and 16... what do those numbers represent.

Comment: what is your precedens rules? ie. how do you know that team violin is more important than violin? Because it's longer?

Comment: @Marc team violin starts at position 11 if you count it by bytes where the beginning of the string is position 0.

Comment: @Marc: It seems the offsets are the characters, with '0' representing the 1st character.

Comment: "showcase their violin talent"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to extract the string first with the larger keyword and retrieve the offset, then replace the large keyword with special chars (#, $, etc.) as many as is needed that length of the string is not gonna change, so when you are searching for the offset of the smaller keyword it won't overlap the larger one.